# Getting error in Jaspersoft Studio when using JPQL Connection

Tags: jpa, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to make a jpql connection using Jaspersoft Studio.

I got the exception below that says that there are no method with name `lockMode()` in `NamedQuery` class. But the method exists.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.data.ejbql.EjbqlDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(EjbqlDataAdapterService.java:70)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.NamedQuery.lockMode()Ljavax/persistence/LockModeType;
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryHintDefinition.determineLockOptions(QueryHintDefinition.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindQuery(QueryBinder.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindQueries(QueryBinder.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindQueries(AnnotationBinder.java:374)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:618)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3790)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3744)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
        ... 35 more
```

This is project dependencies at JSS:

[image]

Comment: so there is a JPA API 1.0 jar elsewhere in the CLASSPATH ...

Comment: no there are no other jpa api 1.0.jar @NeilStockton

Comment: I don't state it as a question. It is a fact. You only get NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.NamedQuery.lockMode()Ljavax/persistence/LockModeType; when the method doesn't exist. So it has found a jar where it doesn't exist for that class (the method was added in JPA 2.0).

Comment: the problem is that the method already exist in calss  javax.persistence.NamedQuery at  hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final jar
and i have checked if there are other class with name namedQuery in classpath but there are no confilct